# Regular Expression for C Identifier

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I am using `Flex` to tokenize an input file so that I could eventually make a simple C compiler using `Bison` as well.

So I am still fooling around with `Flex` and I'm trying to extract numbers and ignore identifiers and white spaces

```
%{

#include "stdio.h"

%}

dgt [0-9]
letter [A-Za-z]
white [ \r\t]+
id {letter}({letter}|{dgt})*
number {dgt}+

%%
{number} return atoi(yytext);
{id} { }
{white} { }

%%

void main(){
    int val=0;
    while( (val=yylex())>0)
    printf("You Entered %d\n",val); 
}
```

The problem here is that with an input file such as this:

```
 hello 123 test assadf507ascv 123asd 0
```

I get this output :

```
You Entered 123
You Entered 123
```

I need it to recognize just numbers, the second output came from `123asd` which is supposed to be an invalid identifier.

Where did I go wrong ?!!
Should I make a rule to detect that case explicitly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your number definition is just looking for 1 or more digits which will match digit groups anywhere, even if they're concatenated with non-digit characters.

```
number {dgt}+
```

which is the RegEx equivalent of:

```
[0-9]+
```

It sounds like you need to test that there are no unwanted characters immediately following the digit characters to extract your valid numbers.  I did this by creating another rule to explicitly match such bad terms, which results in them being ignored as "numbers".

Example: test.flex:

```
%{

#include "stdio.h"

%}

letter [A-Za-z]
white [ \r\t]+
id {letter}({letter}|{dgt})*
dgt [0-9]
number {dgt}+
invalid [0-9]+[a-zA-Z_]+

%%

{id} { }
{white} { }
{invalid} { }
{number} return atoi(yytext);

%%

void main(){
    int val=0;
    while( (val=yylex())>0)
    printf("You Entered %d\n",val);
}
```

You may want to change the second half of the `invalid` definition, depending on which characters you don't want to follow the digits.  Also note that the `invalid` rule must come before the `number` rule so it will match first and discard the invalid terms.

```
hello 123 test assadf507ascv 234asdf 456 0   
You Entered 123
You Entered 456
```

See the [Flex manual chapter on Patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)

Comment: I get it, but why use trailing ? Why not just concatenate?

Comment: Ah, yeah.  Sorry.  I was fiddling with the trailing context when I was trying to get a single rule to match only a number *without* any other characters.  Something like [0-9]+/[^a-zA-Z_].  But that didn't work and I forgot I didn't need the trailing for the final solution.  Answer updated.

Comment: If it wouldn't bother you, would you put back the URL to the manual ? It's very helpul

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with flex but perhaps you can try this:

```
dgt [0-9]
letter [A-Za-z]
white [ \r\t]+
id {letter}({letter}|{dgt})*
number \b{dgt}+\b
```

I don't know if `\b` is supported but in regex it means "word boundary". If it's not supported you can also try:

```
number {white}{dgt}+{white}
```

but do note that this won't capture numbers that appear at the start or end of the line. Perhaps

```
number (^|{white}){dgt}+($|{white})
```